# Flex mobile - touch feedback from device

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, touch, system, feedback

I'd like to set a touch feedback (i.e. sound, vibration etc) for all screen controls to be the same as in system settings on the target mobile device.
Is there an easy way of doing it?
(I don't want to use my own effects, since I want the app to behave 'naturally' for the user - if he/she sets screen touch sound in system settings, I want to follow that.)
Thank you.

Comment: Can you be specific?  What device are you using?  What are the "global" Settings?  What is your app code?  How is your app working compared to Global Settings?  Can you provide a runnable demo?

Comment: Maybe I was a little vague. I want every button touch on in my app to produce same feedback as in any other app on target device (I am talking about Android, but why not iOS also). When I build an app in Flex 4.6, all screen touches (button clicks, list selections etc. are now silent, no matter how target device is configured. I assumed that this feedback can be specified in accordance with device's own settings, so that device will take care of it (i.e. not playing sounds when device is in silent mode etc.)

Comment: I suppose I _could_ use effect events to play my own sounds on touch events, but then app would (a) have to take care of silent mode, and (b) would not play the 'click' sound the user is used to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sounds as regular in desktop flash. :) http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_01.html

Comment: Ok, thanks, but as I commented earlier, question was can I determine and access the _target OS's default sound_ for, say, 'click' action, and play **that** sound when user clicks on a control in my app.